# Laplacian on manifolds with corners

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory

So far I've studied smooth riemannian manifolds and the Laplace-Beltrami operator associated to it. Therefore I know basic theorems like Stoke's theorem, divergence theorem, green's identities etc. and also some basic properties of the Laplacian, e.g. that the eigenvalues for compact manifolds (possibly with Neumann or Dirichlet boundary conditions) consists of an unbounded sequence $\lambda_1<\lambda_2<...$ etc.

Now I'm interested in the study of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on manifolds with corners, e.g. geodesic triangles or rectangles. Can you give me some starting point to beginn with, like some references where the results of the smooth case are generalized to the case I'm now interested in? Or maybe you can tell me in advance which of the results mentioned above can or cannot be generalized?

I'm looking forward for your reply.